# Deleting certain elements in a list

Tags: python, list, range

So I want to delete all multiples of 2 in a list. How can I do it? But there is another question, if I then want to delete all multiples of 3 what happens with six, for example?

Comment: Have you read python documentation on lists? If so, show us your failed efforts.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: can you show some code ?

Answer (score 2):

To delete all multiples of 2 or 3 in a list you would probably want to do a list comprehension where you throw in a condition that filters out integers that can be divided evenly by whatever multiple you are looking for.  If you posted an example of your code I could probably give you better help, but based on your question I suggest the following...

```
nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

no_mult_of_2 = [ x for x in nums if x%2 != 0 ]
no_mult_of_3 = [ x for x in nums if x%3 != 0 ]

print no_mult_of_2
print no_mult_of_3
```

Prints....

```
[1, 3, 5, 7]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
```

As you can see, 6 is gone in both cases because it is a multiple of 2 and 3.  Notice the 0 is missing.  Not sure if you want this to happen or not so keep that in mind.

Also...  Your question is probably recieving so many down votes because the culture here encourages users to try to think about the problem and not just ask for a solution.  I didn't understand this myself at first, and on a few occasions my questions were downvoted.  Don't be discouraged though, we're here to help, just try to show us what kind of progress you've made (examples) when asking a question in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = range(10)
a = filter(lambda n: n%2 != 0, a)
```

it will give you 
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

As you can see, no more six (and the same will happen with any multiple of six)

then, if you delete multiples of three

```
a = filter(lambda n: n%3 != 0, a)
```

a will be [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (if by index):

```
>>> l=range(100)
>>> l[:]=[e for i,e in enumerate(l) if i%2]
```

Or this if it is by the multiple of the value of the elements of the list:

```
>>> l=range(100)
>>> l[:]=[e for e in l if e%2]
```

Use `e` (or `i`) `% 3` for multiples of 3. Since 6 is a multiple of 2 or 3, it will be deleted in either case.

Comment: I think he meant multiple of the actual values in the list not the element index.